# Proving a Certain Functional is Coercive

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, calculus-of-variations

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $C^1$ boundary and let $J:\mathscr{H}^{1}_0(\Omega) \to \mathbb{R}$ be given by:

$$
J(v) = \int_\Omega |v(x)|^p\mathrm{d}x
$$
where $p <\frac{2n}{n-2}$ I want to show that $J$ is coercive, i.e $\lim_{\|v\|_{\mathscr{H}^{1}_0(\Omega)} \to \infty} |J(v)| = \infty$ to set up a later maximization problem. I have tried using a host of inequalities (Sobolev, Holder interpolation) to show the above limit, but they have all failed. The main issue occurs when the $L^2$ norm of $\nabla u$ grows unboundedly, but the $L^2$ norm of $u$ does not. Of course, the $L^2$ norm of $u$ can be controlled above by the norm of its gradient (Poincare inequality), but this does not give us control of the norms from below, which is what I seek.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true. Let $\Omega$ be the unit disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (you can construct similar examples in higher dimensions), $\Omega'=(-R,R)^2$ for some $R<1$, $\eta\in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ with $0\leq \eta\leq 1$, $\eta(x)=1$ for $x\in \Omega'$, and
$$
v_\epsilon(x_1,x_2)=\begin{cases}-1&\text{if }x_1\leq -\epsilon,\\
x/\epsilon&\text{if }-\epsilon<x_1<\epsilon,\\
1&\text{if }x_1\geq \epsilon.\end{cases}
$$
Then $\eta v_\epsilon\in H^1_0(\Omega)$, $\|\eta v_\epsilon\|_p\leq |\Omega|^{1/p}\|\eta v_\epsilon\|_\infty\leq |\Omega|^{1/p}$, yet
$$
\int_{\Omega}|\partial_1(\eta v_\epsilon)|^2\,dx\geq \int_{\Omega'}|\partial_1 v_\epsilon|^2\,dx=\int_{-R}^R \int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}\epsilon^{-2}\,dx_1\,dx_2=4R\epsilon^{-1}\to\infty.
$$

Comment: I had a sneaking suspicion. Thanks. Back to the drawing board I guess.

Comment: Would you happen to know how I could prove this functional attains its maximum on the convex set $\{ u \in \mathscr{H}_0^1(\Omega) : \|u\|_{\mathscr{H}_{0}^{1}(\Omega} \leq 1\}$ ?

Comment: I guess $\Omega$ is bounded, right? In this case use that the unit ball in $H^1_0$ is weakly compact and the functional $J$ is weakly continuous (by Sobolev embedding).

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure how I would show weak continuity of $J$. I was instead thinking of using strong continuity + Rellich Kondrachov (not exactly the same as weak continuity).

Comment: That is what I meant. Compact operators map weakly convergent sequences to strongly convergent ones, so strong continuity of $J$ on $L^p$ implies weak continuity on $H^1_0$.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I'll accept your answer as well.